# Yocto - increase size of rootfs

Tags: yocto

I have read that it is possible to increase the size of the rootfs with the variable IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE. Can someone tell me in which file I have to set this variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE` variable is defined by default to `0` in:

> poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf

So, you can modify it in any `.conf` file such as `local.conf` or in your machine specific configuration file.

Also, you can set it in any image recipe file.

Example:

> meta-example/recipes-core/images/example-image.bb

Comment: Kindly accept the solution if yes.